# Setting path for TexMaths to use latex

Tags: texlive, mac

I just installed installed TexMaths to use latex in Libre Office in my Mac.
I am asked to fill the paths for latex, dvipng and dvisvgm
http://roland65.free.fr/texmaths/install.html . I have tried:

```
/usr/local/texlive
```

and

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016basic
```

But non of them work. It says "The program latex is not located in /usr/local/texlive/2016basic/".

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: What does this have to do with Biblatex?

Comment: Did you install MacTeX? The paths will be under `bin` somewhere. Just have a look in Finder or Terminal. `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/<architecture>/`. `<architecture>` will be something specific to you system e.g. with `darwin` or `mac` or something in it. But you should have a symbolic link somewhere else, only I forget the current details as they've had to change the configuration.

Comment: Ok great, apparently it worked for latex. But now is complaining about dvipng. What are the paths for dvipng and dvisvgm?

Comment: The same. Did you install the full version of MacTeX?

Comment: No, I only installed TexShop

Comment: As explained on the page you linked, you need to install a TeX distribution. But if it found `latex`, you must have some distribution installed, even if it isn't sufficient. TeXShop is just an editor. I don't know why you would install it at all for TeXMath. But it is MacTeX you need regardless.

Comment: Isn't there a way to find where dvipng and dvisvgm are? And if they are not, to install them? The reason why I did not install the full version of MacTex is space restrictions.

Comment: You can try installing them with `tlmgr`, but note that `tlmgr` does not manage dependencies for you. TeX Live Utility is a GUI wrapper for at least the most commonly used `tlmgr` functions, although I've never used it myself. But are you really that short of disk space? Note that even if you are just using it for formulae in LO, a Basic installation will be limited in various ways. (Font selection, additional mathematical symbols etc.)